# Send http request after clicked again with refreshing data

Tags: angular

I am retrieving data over a rest api and after the first request I am not able to refresh my data even if I am subscribing. The rest api deliver me a random data after each request and currently I can just send one request. What I am doing wrong?

**imageContent.component.hmtl**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data;">{{x}}</div>
```

**imageContent.component.ts**

```
this.apiService.callDataForReview()
   .subscribe(result => {this.data=result, console.log(result)},
     error => this.handleError = <any>error);
}
```

**apiService.ts**

```
callDataForReview(): Observable<any> {
         this.isLoading = true;
         let url = '/rest/v4/jobs/' + this.keyID;
         let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
         return this.http
             .post(url, JSON.stringify(this.jsonData), {headers:headers})
             .map((res) => {
                    if (res) {

                        if (res.status === 201) {
                            this.isLoading = false;
                            console.log(res.json().outputValues['json-output-14'])

                            return [res.json().outputValues['json-output-14']];
                        }
                        else if (res.status === 200) {
                            this.isLoading = false;
                          console.log(res.json().outputValues['json-output-14'])

                            return [res.json().outputValues['json-output-14']];
                        }else{
                          alert('Etwas ist schief gelaufen. Probiere es noch einmal!')
                        }
                    }
                }).catch((error: any) => {
                    if (error.status === 500) {
                        return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                    }
                    else if (error.status === 400) {
                        return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                    }
                    else if (error.status === 409) {
                        return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                    }
                    else if (error.status === 406) {
                        return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                    }
                });



         }
```

Comment: so you get unexpected data when you do a `console.log` in the first callback of map i.e. `res` ? And I guess you must return something. You aren't returning anything in your else block.